# put text in the upper center of another div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put names in the middle of the div of the gold podium (no matter the number Of letters in the word).

I gave 3 examples for the gold podium:

[image]

this is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alonshmiel/9rY3k/3/

I tried to let `left` the calculation of the width of the screen and to reduce the (width of the gold div) / 2. but it didn't work. the words start in the same place.

```
<div class="podium-block gold">
    <span class="place">1st place</span>
<span class="sum">$5000</span>
<span class="name">Jacob Collins</span>
    <div class="podium"></div>
</div>
```

any help appreciated!

Comment: Try this: top: 185px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correcting the last part of the JQuery, it works:

```
$('.name').delay(1000).animate({
    "opacity": "1"
}, 500);
```

Alhough as it is said in the comment below, it can be solved using CSS

Comment: Why is a Javascript version the accepted answer when CSS can be used perfectly? Why use JS when it's not needed. It adds bloat where there should be none.

Comment: The code in the question has been changed and my answer is absolutely out of context now. And of course I agree 100% with your comment, @webnoob ;)

Comment: Ah ok :) Sorry for the rant in that case :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is what you are trying to achieve, but here is the `CSS` solution:

```
.podium {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.podium > * {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff; /* not needed, just for clarity */
    font-size: 16px; /* not needed, just for clarity */
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9rY3k/6/)

For aligning the text top change `vertical-align: middle;` to `vertical-align: top;`